# Access previous elements in lapply/sapply

Tags: r, lapply, sapply

I´m trying to replace a `for` loop with a `sapply` function. Inside the loop I do some optimization and therefore need the result of one optimization for the next loop.

I figured out how to use the `sapply` to run the optimization but the problem is that I need to access the previous results from within the `sapply`.

The following is just a random example of what I´m trying to achieve.

```
sapply(1:4, function(y){
  r<-y
  if(y!=1){z<-r[y-1]}
  else{z<-9}
  return(z)
  })

[1,]    9    2   NA   NA
```

What I expected to get was something like:

```
[1,]    9    1    2   3
```

What am I doing wrong? Or isn´t there any way to access previous results of iterations in `sapply`?

Comment: You can't. The only solution would be to write to some other environment (e.g. using `<<-`) and retrieve the result.

Comment: You can't do this using an `apply` function. You may be able to achieve this using `Reduce` if you want to stay in the functional style of programming.

Comment: @Andrie would be interested in a solution and its timing. Can come handy for long MCMCMC runs.

Comment: IMO a good old loop is the way to go...

Comment: PS. There are no fundamentally good reasons to avoid loops in R. Loops are not inherently slow. It is growing vectors that are slow. So, pre-allocate a vector and you'll be good.

Comment: I suggest you give [R inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) a read.

Comment: lots of passion here today. is this the general idea of what you want? `z <- numeric(4); r <- 1:4; for (y in 1:4) z[y] <- if (y!=1) r[y-1] else 9`

Comment: It is clear that the example code you gave doesn't reflect your real situation. Can you design a better example?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik No use in timing `Reduce`. It's a hidden R level `for` loop.

Comment: I tried the approach with the other environment `<<-` Probably not the most elegant solution. But it seems to work.

Answer (score 13):

Here is an example perhaps closer to the OP's use case:

```
f    = function(x) x^2
g    = function(x) abs(x)+rnorm(1)
yvec = 1:4
```

Here's the `Reduce` approach mentioned by @Andrie:

```
set.seed(1)
Reduce(function(z,y) if (is.na(z)) f(y) else g(z), yvec,init=NA_real_,accumulate=TRUE)[-1]
# [1]  1.0000000  0.3735462  0.5571895 -0.2784391
```

And here's a common-sense loop that everyone would use (mentioned by @digEmAll):

```
set.seed(1)
res <- rep(NA_real_,length(yvec))
for (i in seq_along(yvec)) res[i] = if (i==1) f(yvec[i]) else g(res[i-1])
res
# [1]  1.0000000  0.3735462  0.5571895 -0.2784391
```

The results are the same, so, `Reduce` just hides the loop, as asserted by @Roland.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot access the previous result with the apply family of functions. They are wrappers for `for` loops so there is no reason to avoid the loops explicitly if that is what you are after.

To your question "What am I doing wrong?". With your function:

```
sapply(1:4, function(y){
  r<-y
  if(y!=1){z<-r[y-1]}
  else{z<-9}
  return(z)
  })
```

In the expression `r[y-1]`, NA's are produced after the first two loops.

When `1` is passed through, it goes to the `else` statement and `z` is assigned `9`. When `2` is passed through, it goes to the expression `r[y-1]`. In that iteration `r` is equal to `2` and so is `y`. So it is equivalent to `2[2-1]`, which simplifies to `2[1]`. That can be read as "the first element of the vector `2`. Answer being `2`.

On the next round, `r` equals `3` and so does `y`. The expression is now `3[3-1]`. Simplified to `3[2]`. That's a problem because what is the 2nd element of the vector `3`? There is none, it only has one element. So `NA` is returned. That same effect happens for the rest of the loop.

Comment: How is this accessing result from a previous iteration?

Comment: The way I understand (and it would appear also Andrie and digEmAll) is that OP needs explicit access to a result generated in a previous iteration. Recalculating that result work done twice.

Comment: You are not addressing the `I need to access the previous results from within the sapply` part of the question. Imagine that the result is a stochastic process in which case you can't just recalculate the result the way you propose OP does.

Comment: @Pierre Lafortune: thanks for your suggestion. The problem is that the above code is only an easy example of what I´m trying to do. In reality I´m optimizing using the lpsolveAPI within the sapply function. I would then need the previous optimization result from the 2nd iteration on.